# How to update 2nd table with identity value of inserted rows into 1st table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table structures

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorkItem](
    [WorkItemId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WorkItemTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [WorkItemStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClosedDate] [datetime] NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RequirementWorkItem](
    [WorkItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RequirementId] [int] NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE #RequirmentWorkItems
(
    RequirementId int,
    WorkItemTypeId int,
    WorkItemStatusId int,
    ActionDate datetime
)
```

I use the `#RequirmentWorkItems` table to create workitems for requirements.  I then need to INSERT the workitems into the `WorkItem` table and use the identity values from the `WorkItem` table to create the cross-reference rows in the `RequirementWorkItem` table.

Is there a way to do this without cursoring thru each row?  And I can't put the `RequirementId` into the `WorkItem` table because depending on the `WorkItemTypeId` the `WorkItem` could be linked to a `Requirement` or a `Notice` or an `Event`.

So there are really 3 xref tables for `WorkItems`.  Or would it be better to put a `RequirementId`, `NoticeId` and `EventId` in the `WorkItem` table and 1 of the columns would have a value and other 2 would be null?  Hopefully all this makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [MERGE and OUTPUT – the swiss army knife of T-SQL](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/01/06/merge-and-output-the-swiss-army-knife-of-t-sql.aspx) for more information about this.

> Today I stumbled upon a different use for it, returning values using an OUTPUT clause from a table used as the source of data for an insertion. In other words, if I’m inserting from [tableA] into [tableB] then I may want some values from [tableA] after the fact, particularly if [tableB] has an identity. Observe my first attempt using a straight insertion where I am trying to get a field from @source.[id] that is not used in the insertion:

Comment: That's pretty sweet.  I looked at examples of using OUTPUT and MERGE separately to do what I needed to do, but never together like that.  Works like a charm.  Thank you so much.